# Return list python

Tags: python

well I have this code returns me a list:

```
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp import debug
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import cmdrsp, context, ntforg
from pysnmp.carrier.asynsock.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.smi import builder

import threading
import collections
import time

MibObject = collections.namedtuple('MibObject', ['mibName',
                                   'objectType', 'valueFunc'])


class Mib(object):
    """Stores the data we want to serve. 
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._lock = threading.RLock()
        self._test_count = 0
        self._test_get = 10
        self._test_set = 0 

    def getTestDescription(self):
        return "My Description"

    def getTestCount(self):
        with self._lock:
            return self._test_count

    def setTestCount(self, value):
        with self._lock:
            self._test_count = value

    def getTestGet(self):
        return self._test_get

    def getTestSet(self):
        return self._test_set

    def setTestSet(self):
        with self._lock:
            self._test_set = value

class ListObject:

    def __init__(self): 
        mib = Mib()
        self.objects = [
            MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testDescription', mib.getTestDescription),
            MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testCount', mib.getTestCount),
            MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testGet', mib.getTestGet),
            MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testSet', mib.getTestSet)
        ]
    def returnTest(self):
        return ListObject()

class main ():        
    print ListObject()
```

but sometimes it returns the object variable and it returns me this:

```
<__main__.ListObject instance at 0x16917e8>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sometimes? This code always seems to return it.

Comment: What did you expect to be printed instead?

Comment: this: [MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testDescription', mib.getTestDescription),
         MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testCount', mib.getTestCount),MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testGet', mib.getTestGet), MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testSet',           mib.getTestSet) ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an object to python `print`, the printed string is given by its class '**str**' method.

`<main.ListObject instance at 0x16917e8>` is the string returned by the default implementation of `__str__` method. If you haven't overridden this method for your class, the result is just the expected.

**EDIT:**

If what you want is to print `objects` when you write `print ListObject()` you have to override `ListObject` `__str__(self)` method:

```
class ListObject:
    def __str__(self):
        return self.objects.__str__()
```

Comment: understand, but it has some way of returning that object list?

Comment: @PauloVagner Edited my answer override `__str__`.

Comment: Thank you, you were a big help !